# in python, is it a bad practice to use a property which doesn't return an instance variable?

Tags: python, properties

Ok, let's say that I want to create a Vector2d in python to represent two-dimensional vectors. Now, I want to have a property to get the magnitude of the vector, so I code the next class:

```
class Vector2d:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        return (self._x**2 + self._y**2)**(1/2)
```

I know I could use normal methods to do things like this, but I think that this way is more simple to use my class, so the question is, is it considered a bad practice?

Comment: The only bad practice I see is to mark `x` and `y` as "should be used privately" by the underscore.

Comment: This is *the whole point* of `property`. In fact, if all your property does is something like `return self._x` then *that is* a bad practice, because then it should just be an attribute (unless you are trying to prevent assignment to that property by defining only a getter without a setter/deleter)